# Finding data from mongodb with variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
db.collection('practice').find({"key":obj})
```

`obj` is the value of an input box. When I `console.log(obj)` I get its value but when I use it in this function it doesn't find anything. When I do `find({})` it returns my whole database so I know it's working. Just wondering how to list the variable so it only finds the data with the obj name.

example of working JSON:

```
[{"_id":"5b9d1e06b355f116cb8cf0bb","key":"John"}]
```

The "John" comes from what I typed into the input box. If I typed a different name it would look like {"key" : "different name"}. This part works fine. The problem is that I want to then use this obj variable to find all the data that is equal to the obj variable. For example, if I typed in John, it would show me only where the key = john.

Comment: What is `obj`? What is `key` supposed to be?

Comment: Could be a case-sensitivity problem? E.g. your `obj` variable contains "test" but your db contains a value of "Test" or something similar... Have you tried logging the queries (`db.setLogLevel(1)`) or running the same query using a different client?

Comment: please provide sample of your practice collection,and sample of obj content

Comment: What  you have should work: https://mongoplayground.net/p/y7XMDfZe-xe